# quickbloxsdk : Passed object is not file,Incorrect content type?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, quickblox

I am working on quickblox message attachment functionality in android.

What all I am trying to do is : `OnViewClicked` one `CreateChooser(type:images/*)` would be open.
After selecting an image it will come to `onActivityResult` method where it stores `Uri`.
Post that `sendAttachment` function is being called.

Here is my coding portion :

```
private Uri uri;
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the Uri of the selected file
                uri = data.getData();
            }
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public void sendAttachment() {

        File filePhoto = new File(uri.getPath());
        Boolean fileIsPublic = false;

        QBContent.uploadFileTask(filePhoto, fileIsPublic, null, new QBProgressCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressUpdate(int i) {
                // i - progress in percentages
                Log.e(TAG, "onProgressUpdate: " + i);
            }
        }).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBFile>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBFile qbFile, Bundle bundle) {

                Integer id = qbFile.getId();

                // create a message
                QBChatMessage chatMessage = new QBChatMessage();
                chatMessage.setProperty("save_to_history", "1"); // Save a message to history

                // attach a photo
                QBAttachment attachment = new QBAttachment("photo");
                attachment.setId(qbFile.getId().toString());
                chatMessage.setBody("");
                chatMessage.addAttachment(attachment);

                // send a message
                try {
                    mQBChatDialog.sendMessage(chatMessage);
                    mtvEmpty.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException errors) {
                Log.e("DATA", TextUtils.join(",", errors.getErrors()));
            }
        });
}
```

LOGCAT ERROR :

> E/ERROR: File upload onError,File does not exist,Passed object is not file,Incorrect content type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out a solution on this.

This type of error displays whenever you try to add **file that does not exist on your device physically.**

To resolve the problem I simply downloaded new file & my code worked with a  charm.

Comment: can you please share a sample code for these issue. I have to upload image from camara/gallery

Comment: @Pallavi What exactly you want?..
I mean uploadFileTask only or File Selection from gallary + uploadFileTask?

Comment: I have gallary part but I want to sync both

Comment: Please up-vote this answer, If helped. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

**Try below Code.It works for me to upload image,video and audio**

```
public void uploadAttachment(final File file, final int fileType) {

    String tags = CollectionsUtils.getMimeType(Uri.fromFile(file));
    ChatHelper.getInstance().loadFileAsAttachment(file,  tags, new QBEntityCallback<QBAttachment>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBAttachment result, Bundle params) {
            fileUploadProgressMap.remove(item);
            result.setType(String.valueOf(fileType));
            fileQBAttachmentMap.put(item, result);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
            onAttachmentUploadErrorListener.onAttachmentUploadError(e);
            remove(item);
        }
    }, new QBProgressCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressUpdate(final int progress) {
            fileUploadProgressMap.put(item, progress);
            mainThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

```
 public void loadFileAsAttachment(File file, String tags, QBEntityCallback<QBAttachment> callback,
                                 QBProgressCallback progressCallback) {
    QBContent.uploadFileTask(file, true, tags, progressCallback)
            .performAsync(new QbEntityCallbackTwoTypeWrapper<QBFile, QBAttachment>(callback) {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QBFile qbFile, Bundle bundle) {
                    QBAttachment attachment = new QBAttachment(QBAttachment.PHOTO_TYPE);
                    attachment.setId(qbFile.getId().toString());
                    attachment.setUrl(qbFile.getPublicUrl());
                    callback.onSuccess(attachment, bundle);
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather using `uri.getPath()` for getting the file please use `uri.getLastPathSegment()`.